# Hibernate MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have two tables table1 and table2 in MySQL database. When user1 performs some operation, it updates row1 in table1 and then performs some operation-X and then updates row1 in table2. while my code is performing this operation-X, some other user, say user2, updates the row1 in table2. If this happens then operation-X performed by user1 will not update the row1 in table2. I want to create  write lock in both the rows of the table so that unless this operation-X is complete and update happens in the table2, I don't want the user2 to update that particular row in table2.
I am using hibernate template for updating etc. in the MySQL database.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The usual strategy is to use optimistic locking, as described in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e5844). It simply consists in adding a column and a corresponding field to the entity, annotated with `@Version`:

```
@Version
private Long version;
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific. I am a newbie in spring hibernate.

Comment: Have you clicked the link to the documentation and read the section about optimistic locking? What don't you understand in it?